# Zoom_changed - Center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been stuck on this for a while and therefore simplified my 
requirement. 
When you click on a marker an infowindow opens, when a user zooms I 
want that marker to be in the center of the map. 
This doesn't work but I think it's close:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
      }); 
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
                infoWindow.setCenter(infoWindow.getCenter()); 
                }); 
    }
```

http://www.hostelbars.com/map_test_v3_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you do `infoWindow.setCenter(infoWindow.getCenter());` This will get the center of the `infoWindow` and not the `marker`. Try doing something like this:

`infoWindow.setCenter(marker.getPosition());`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't achieve what I want to do as when I zoom the open infowindow doesn't move to the center of the map. Are you able to help further? thanks

Comment: Try `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { 
                infoWindow.setCenter(infoWindow.getCenter()); map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()) 
                });`